# Radar Plot Matplotlib Python : how to set label alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, radar-chart

I am trying to align labels of my radar plot with axis and I face difficulties.

Without label alignment, my labels are centered and exceed the axis line [image].

When I set for the first half of my labels (the right side of the figure) alignment to left and for the second half the alignment to the right I get a non "circular" alignment [image]

To do so I looped within xticklabels and set horizontal alignment.

```
# Draw one axe per variable + add labels labels yet
plt.xticks(angles, categories)
for label,i in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),range(0,len(angles))):
    if i<len(angles)/2:
        angle_text=angles[i]*(-180/pi)+90
        #label.set_horizontalalignment('left')

    else:
        angle_text=angles[i]*(-180/pi)-90
        #label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    label.set_rotation(angle_text)
```

I guess there is a proper way to do this and I can't figure it out, as I don't know if it should consider an offset, a translation or how to adapt the polar coordinate to do so.

Thanks for your help

Paul

Here follows the full code for more information

```
from math import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

## Generate Data
labels_test=[]
for i in range(0,40):
    labels_test.append("Fooooooooo"+str(i))
pd_radar=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(2, 40)),columns=labels_test)

# number of variable
categories=list(pd_radar)
N = len(categories)

# What will be the angle of each axis in the plot? (we divide the plot / number of variable)
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]

# Initialise the spider plot
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# If you want the first axis to be on top:
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Draw one axe per variable + add labels labels yet
plt.xticks(angles, categories)
for label,i in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),range(0,len(angles))):
    if i<len(angles)/2:
        angle_text=angles[i]*(-180/pi)+90
        label.set_horizontalalignment('left')

    else:
        angle_text=angles[i]*(-180/pi)-90
        label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    label.set_rotation(angle_text)
# Draw ylabels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)


# ------- PART 2: Add plots

# Plot each line of the data 

# Ind1
values0=pd_radar.iloc[0].values.flatten().tolist()
ax.plot(angles, values0, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="Label 1",color='yellow')
ax.fill(angles, values0, 'r', alpha=0.1,color='yellow')

# Ind2
values1=pd_radar.iloc[1].values.flatten().tolist()
ax.plot(angles, values1, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="Label 2",color='deepskyblue')
ax.fill(angles, values1, 'r',color='deepskyblue', alpha=0.1)

# Add legend
plt.show()
```

Comment: ok thanks, hope it is clearer

Comment: Yep, except that I currently cannot reproduce this. Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: matplotlib.__version__='2.0.2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The code currently [does not run with matplotlib 2.2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10882). The following solution works however with version 2.0.2 that the OP is using. For a workaround using newer versions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719340/how-to-rotate-tick-labels-in-polar-matplotlib-plot).*

Texts in matplotlib have a [rotation mode](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_text_rotation_mode.html).

The rotation mode can be `"default"`, in which case the text is first rotated and then aligned

[image]

or it can be `"anchor"`, in which case the text is first aligned and then rotated.

[image]

Therefore, in order to have the ticklabels pointing outwards on the polar plot, you would want to set the alignment of the text to `"left"`, but then set the rotation mode to `"anchor"`.

```
for label,rot in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),ticks):
    label.set_rotation(rot*180./np.pi)
    label.set_horizontalalignment("left")
    label.set_rotation_mode("anchor")
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

ticks = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20, endpoint=False)
text = lambda : "".join(np.random.choice(list("manuladefil"), size=10))
labels = [text() for _ in range(len(ticks))]

plt.xticks(ticks, labels, size=16)
for label,rot in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),ticks):
    label.set_rotation(rot*180./np.pi)
    label.set_horizontalalignment("left")
    label.set_rotation_mode("anchor")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this example isnt working for me

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that doesn't seems elegant. Main idea was to set both vertical and horizontal alignment as a function of the angle.

[image]

```
from math import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Generate Data
labels_test=[]
for i in range(0,40):
    labels_test.append("Fooooooooo"+str(i))
pd_radar=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(2, 40)),columns=labels_test)


# number of variable
categories=list(pd_radar)
N = len(categories)

# What will be the angle of each axis in the plot? (we divide the plot / number of variable)
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]

# Initialise the spider plot
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# If you want the first axis to be on top:
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Draw one axe per variable + add labels labels yet
# idea is to add both vertical and horizontal alignment as a function of pi

plt.xticks(angles, categories)
for label,i in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),range(0,len(angles))):

    angle_rad=angles[i]
    if angle_rad <= pi/2:
        ha= 'left'
        va= "bottom"
        angle_text=angle_rad*(-180/pi)+90
    elif pi/2 < angle_rad <= pi:
        ha= 'left'
        va= "top"
        angle_text=angle_rad*(-180/pi)+90
    elif pi < angle_rad <= (3*pi/2):
        ha= 'right'
        va= "top"  
        angle_text=angle_rad*(-180/pi)-90
    else:
        ha= 'right'
        va= "bottom"
        angle_text=angle_rad*(-180/pi)-90
    label.set_rotation(angle_text)
    label.set_verticalalignment(va)
    label.set_horizontalalignment(ha)


# Draw ylabels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)


# ------- PART 2: Add plots

# Plot each line of the data 

# Ind1
values2=pd_radar.iloc[0].values.flatten().tolist()
ax.plot(angles, values2, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="Label 1",color='yellow')
ax.fill(angles, values2, 'r', alpha=0.1,color='yellow')

# Ind2
values3=pd_radar.iloc[1].values.flatten().tolist()
ax.plot(angles, values3, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="Label 2",color='deepskyblue')
ax.fill(angles, values3, 'r',color='deepskyblue', alpha=0.1)

# Add legend
plt.show()
```

Comment: this script isnt working for me