# Add gap between label and radar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a radar chart to visualize some key figures.

So I took the code from [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/390-basic-radar-chart/) and changed it a little bit, so it would fit my needs.

Here is the code that I use for my radar chart:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

categories=['consistency', 'correctness', 'completeness']
N = len(categories)

values=[59,80,60]
values += values[:1]
values

angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

ax = f.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=8)

ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
plt.yticks([20,40,60,80,100], ["20","40","60","80","100"], color="grey", size=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)

ax.plot(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')

ax.fill(angles, values, 'b', alpha=0.1)
```

One thing I noticed, that the labels are way to close to the radar chart as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJlGy.png), because they are longer than the labels that are used in examples of radar charts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488018/radar-plot-matplotlib-python-how-to-set-label-alignment

Comment: Please *answer* the question instead of providing a solution in the question. (Else, what's the question?)

Comment: @bbd108 Tanks,I found the solution in the link you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in the post linked in the comment section.

Here is the changed code:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

categories=['consistency', 'correctness', 'completeness']
N = len(categories)

values=[59,80,60]
values += values[:1]
values

angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

ax = f.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=10)

for label,i in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(),range(0,len(angles))):

    angle_rad=angles[i]
    if angle_rad <= pi/2:
        ha= 'left'
        va= "bottom"

    elif pi/2 < angle_rad <= pi:
        ha= 'right'
        va= "bottom"

    elif pi < angle_rad <= (3*pi/2):
        ha= 'right'
        va= "top"  

    else:
        ha= 'right'
        va= "bottom"

    label.set_verticalalignment(va)
    label.set_horizontalalignment(ha)

ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
plt.yticks([20,40,60,80,100], ["20","40","60","80","100"], color="grey", size=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)

ax.plot(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')

ax.fill(angles, values, 'b', alpha=0.1)
```

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7d8e.png) the labels are now positioned correctly.

Comment: I believe "else" needs to be ha="left", va="top" (at least based on my testing). Otherwise absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided does not take direction and offset into account.
In my radar chart I have an offset of pi/2, so that the first axis is at the top (rather than the right) and a direction of -1 (so the axes are positioned in clockwise direction, instead of the default counterclockwise)

```
    # If you want the first axis to be on top:
    ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
    # If you want labels to go clockwise (counterclockwise is default)
    ax.set_theta_direction(direction='clockwise')
```

Anyway, I slightly modified your solution to include those as well:

```
    rstep = int(ax.get_theta_direction())
    if rstep > 0:
        rmin = 0
        rmax = len(angles)
    else:
        rmin = len(angles)-1
        rmax = -1

    for label, i in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), range(rmin, rmax, rstep)):
        angle_rad = angles[i] + ax.get_theta_offset()
        if angle_rad <= pi / 2:
            ha = 'left'
            va = "bottom"
        elif pi / 2 < angle_rad <= pi:
            ha = 'right'
            va = "bottom"
        elif pi < angle_rad <= (3 * pi / 2):
            ha = 'right'
            va = "top"
        else:
            ha = 'left'
            va = "top"
        label.set_verticalalignment(va)
        label.set_horizontalalignment(ha)
```

Note that there was also a small error in the 'else:' bit in the answer. ha/va set to right/bottom where it should be left/top there.
(Not noticeable with the example chart since it does not have a label in that quadrant).